# Clickable MyLocationOverlay

Tags: android, maps, ontouchlistener, clickable, mylocationoverlay

Is it possible to make the MyLocationOverlay marker clickable? I have to launch a spinner when the overlay marker is clicked.

```
myLocationOverlay.setTouchEventListener(new OverlayTouchEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTouch(MotionEvent arg0, MapView arg1) {
            showLocationOverlayDialog();
            Log.i("MainMapActivity", "Main.getView() — location touched");
        }
    });
```

This is what I have so far. I haven't started with the spinner yet. But with this code, I think it's not working. It does not enter the setTouchEventListener. Could anybody please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create subclass of `MyLocationOverlay` and override `dispatchTap()`. Than just create `myLocationOverlay`  as instance of this class